# Is there a structure theory for finite groups of the following form?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, finitely-generated

Consider finite groups of the form $G=\langle g,s \rangle$ generated by two elements, such that $s$ is order $p$, and it generates the (cyclic) sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, $g$ is of order coprime to $p$, and there exists a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $H$ is index $p$, so we have a normal $p$ complement.

Is this family of groups "classifiable"? I am being purposely loose with the word classifiable here, even if a precise classification isn't possible, can we say anything precise about the internal structure of $G$?

Any references that deal with the structure of such groups would also be much appreciated, I only know theorems that give existence of $p$ complements, but they don't really address the internal structure.

Comment: So either $G$ is cyclic, or we gave a group $H$ of order coprime to $p$ with an automorphism $f$ of order $p$ such that $H = \langle g,f(g),f^2(g),\ldots,f^{p-1}(g) \rangle$ for some $g \in H$.  I am afraid the question needs a bit more focus. Do you have anything in mind about the sort of structural properties that you are hoping for?

Comment: I think structurally I am wondering whether this restriction gives enough control to restrict the composition factors of G, since in the case of p complement simple, we are constrained by not many coprime automorphisms of finite simple groups, and in the solvable case this condition seems to give information about the abelianisation of the complement. I’m not very familiar with these kinds of analyses though, so I realise this might still be too vague/not the right kind of questions to ask.